# Linker error while building unit tests with Boost

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, gcc, boost

I'm using gcc 4.8.2 with Boost 1.59. I run on Kubuntu 12.04 LTS. I'm just trying to write a simple unit test application and I'm experiencing linker error.

Here is my code:

**main.cpp**

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE My Module
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```

**test1.cpp**

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( suite1 );
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( case1 )
{
    BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE( "Hello!" );
}
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END();
```

When I build I do: `g++ -std=c++11 -o test main.cpp test1.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_unit_test_framework`. And I get this result:

```
/tmp/ccmNLUMx.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
test1.cpp:(.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `boost::unit_test::ut_detail::auto_test_unit_registrar::auto_test_unit_registrar(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>)'
test1.cpp:(.text+0x1b9): undefined reference to `boost::unit_test::ut_detail::auto_test_unit_registrar::auto_test_unit_registrar(boost::unit_test::test_case*, unsigned long)'
/tmp/ccmNLUMx.o: In function `boost::unit_test::make_test_case(boost::unit_test::callback0<boost::unit_test::ut_detail::unused> const&, boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>)':
test1.cpp: (.text._ZN5boost9unit_test14make_test_caseERKNS0_9callback0INS0_9ut_detail6unusedEEENS0_13basic_cstringIKcEE[_ZN5boost9unit_test14make_test_caseERKNS0_9callback0INS0_9ut_detail6unusedEEENS0_13basic_cstringIKcEE]+0x6d): undefined reference to `boost::unit_test::test_case::test_case(boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const>, boost::unit_test::callback0<boost::unit_test::ut_detail::unused> const&)'
collect2: erreur: ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécution
```

Do you have any idea about what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Dominique

**EDIT**

What is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767699/boost-test-undefined-reference-errors?lq=1) could not solve my problem... :-(

Comment: Can you please post the command to compile that you tried after trying the solution in the link you posted in the EDIT section?

Comment: @jayant I took it "successful" command: `g++ -I/usr/local/include -o test main.cpp  -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-Bdynamic -lboost_unit_test_framework`. Same error. It looks there is something missing. The author uses Boost 1.52, I use 1.59. I built it myself from the source code... I'm pretty confused because I could easily build tests few years ago with previous version of Boost. I'm not saying that there is a bug with 1.59 but rather than my 1.59 installation is maybe wrong???

Comment: I found the solution, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644914/boost-test-cannot-find-main/33659967#33659967).

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem. My solution is, change the include path:

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp> // wrong  
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp> // this work
```

I had found the solution in the first example of [boost unit test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/test_cases/test_organization_nullary.html). I test it with boost 1.60 and gcc 4.8.5

Comment: This helped me with Boost 1.58 and the SunPro compiler V 12.5 on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Worked for me too, but compile time went up 10x for that one file!

Comment: This worked for me, I was able to run and pass tests with clang + libc++ + boost, but the include leaks memory so I have to generate suppressions.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` to compile options resolved this for me