# Boost Test Error: main already defined

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test

I have a `Visual Studio` project where I want to do some unit tests with `Boost.Test`.

And I have 2 files:

File 1:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE FileX

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(test_suite_name)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(TestFileX)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(true);
}


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

And File 2:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE XContainer

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(test_suite_name2)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(TestXContainer)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

When I compile the project I get a link error that's saying that main is already defined.
I noticed that `main` file is defined in `unit_test.hpp` but I need to include it for the test macros.

How should I add 2 test cases in 2 separate file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Boost.Test: Looking for a working non-Trivial Test Suite Example / Tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906095/boost-test-looking-for-a-working-non-trivial-test-suite-example-tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use
`#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK`
in every source file with tests.

Answer (score 10):

The real problem is that BOOST_TEST_MODULE is only ever intended to be defined once in your entire test executable.  Defining BOOST_TEST_MODULE also defines BOOST_TEST_MAIN which pulls in an implementation of main.

So in one single place define BOOST_TEST_MODULE to be the name of your global suite and therefore also define BOOST_TEST_MAIN to get a single implementation of main.

This is a subtlety that I will need to note in my [documentation rewrite](http://user.xmission.com/~legalize/boost.test/libs/test/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your documentation. Everything I needed was in "Header only" section: http://user.xmission.com/~legalize/boost.test/libs/test/doc/html/test/guide/compilation/header_only.html/index.html

Comment: They've since rewritten the documentation for boost.test and it is much better now.  At some point I will delete the content at the above link, but I'm lazy :)

Comment: I too found @legalize's documentation to be the only thing that actually explained concisely, with examples, what to do in the multi-file case.

Answer (score 0):

testXXX.h shouldn't be included in testXXX.cpp.

All of testXXX.h files should be included in main.cpp which should contain `#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE TestXXXXXXXXX`