# Boost C++: Unit Test + Build - Multiple Sources

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

This post is a continuation to [Boost Unit Test Framework with Multiple Sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2907582/4366367)

When the following piece of code (borrowed from [the aforementioned post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2907582/4366367))

```
// test_main.cpp
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Main
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

// test1.cpp
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#ifdef STAND_ALONE
#   define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Main
#endif
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(test1_suite)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(Test1)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(2<1);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()

// test2.cpp
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#ifdef STAND_ALONE
#   define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Main
#endif
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(test2_suite)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(Test1)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(1<2);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

is compiled, ([as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2907582/4366367)) with

```
$ g++ test_main.cpp test1.cpp test2.cpp -lboost_unit_test_framework -o tests
```

How do I achieve this using Boost.Build (to compile and test from multiple sources for Boost Unit Test Framework using Boost.Build)?

Comment: Your question is _extremely_ brief. Can you expand on your goal and your problem?

Comment: Expanded on the context.. Hope a little clearer

Comment: You link to a post but there's no link...?

Comment: I must have been out of mind... Corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

In order to compile and run the unit test with [Boost.Build rule unit-test](http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/builtins/testing.html), create the following `Jamfile`

```
unit-test test_all
  : [ glob test*.cpp ] /root//boost_test
  ;
```

and define the libraries in `/home/<user>/user-config.jam` as follows

```
project root ;
lib boost_test : : <name>boost_unit_test_framework ;
```

Also refer [this nabble thread](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Compiling-multiple-sources-td4660288.html)